# Setting up Robolectric in Bazel

Tags: robolectric, bazel

I’m having some trouble setting up Robolectric for a Bazel build system, mostly due to the number of dependencies it requires.

There doesn’t seem to be one single JAR containing Robolectric and all of its dependencies.  Because of that, I’ve tried both:

1. Creating a `new_git_repository` rule in my WORKSPACE file with a custom BUILD file which compiles the Java sources from the [Robolectric repo](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric).
2. [Downloading all JARs for Robolectric’s dependencies](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2292#issuecomment-185283197), then bundling these up in a `java_import` which my test rules can depend on.

In the first case, I ran into issues trying to generate Java code from provided Groovy classes and still had to manually include several other dependencies. In the second case, I had issues with where Robolectric’s `MavenDependencyResolver` wouldn't be able to find certain dependencies at runtime, which lead to having to manually include the missing dependency JAR files.

Either way, this seems a bit cumbersome to have Bazel compile and run Robolectric tests. Is there a better approach to using Robolectric in a Bazel build system?

Comment: This [blogpost](http://robolectric.org/blog/2017/03/01/hermetic-builds/) might be a good resource. I found it after reading [this github issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2292) discussing using Bazel.

Comment: FWIW, first class robolectric support for Bazel is in the works. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took another stab at this, and the approach where I download all the JARs for Robolectric’s dependencies is what worked for me. The parts I was initially missing were the jvm flags to let Robolectric know it should look for its dependencies locally, not through Maven.   I followed the steps from the [blog post](http://robolectric.org/blog/2017/03/01/hermetic-builds/) zlalanne suggested to download all the JARs, moved those into a directory my project has access to, then created a build target for these:

```
java_import(
  name = "robolectric",
  jars = glob([
      "*.jar",
  ]),
  visibility = [
      "//visibility:public",
  ],
)
```

Then I created a new rule that will provides the correct Robolectric dependencies & jvm flags to the standard java_test rule:

```
def android_robolectric_test(name, deps=[], srcs=[], test_class="", visibility=None):
  androidPlatform = [Label('@androidsdk//:platforms/android-25/android.jar')]
  robolectricDeps = androidPlatform + [Label(“//path/to/robolectric:robolectric")]

  native.java_test(
    name=name,
    srcs=srcs,
    deps=robolectricDeps + deps,
    test_class=test_class,
    jvm_flags=[
      "-Drobolectric.offline=true",
      "-Drobolectric.dependency.dir=‘path/to/robolectric/’”,
    ],
    visibility=visibility,
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now available as the [`android_local_test` rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/android.html#android_local_test).